# Where can I find this definition of "expected value"?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, statistics

I need bibliography or some text about this definition:

"Define the **expected value** of a function by:
$E_{t}(x(t))=(\frac{1}{t})\int_{0}^{t} x(s)ds$. "

I think that it's statistics or functional analysis, but I not remember.

Comment: It is often called average value in calculus texts. One could think of it as ordinary expected value of the function of a random variable, where the random variable is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,t)$.

Comment: From the way its formulated, it looks like a cumulative moving average. Here a discussion: https://qkdb.wordpress.com/tag/cumulative-moving-average/

Comment: Thanks @Bey for your contribution.

Comment: Thanks you @AndréNicolas, I remember the average value in calculus!

Comment: You are welcome. It can indeed be viewed as an expectation for a function of a uniformly distributed random variable. I do not recognize the context of your question, so cannot decide what it is about expectation you might need to know.